# Yii2 Basic : Where is the code for pagination in index.php located?

Tags: datatable, pagination, yii2, php-7

in my index.php I have a table that list out the data limit to 40 row per page. Here I'm using GridView::widget to display the data. The thing is, where is the code for pagination in index.php located? Because when I remove the GridView the pagination also been remove. But I could not find the code for pagination. Help me Please...

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/custom-pagination-in-yiiframework-2-0/   It migh help you

Comment: The pagination is a public property of the [data provider](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider) what is set as default to [yii\data\Pagination](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-pagination), so the code is there, exactly in the file vendor/yiisoft/yii2/data/Pagination.php

Answer (score 0):

The code of pagination was defined on ModelSearch.php on an ActiveDataProvider instance variable with the key pageSize=>40, change that value and ActiveDataProvider will be doing the rest. Maybe it is located on models folder or another folder named Search or ModelSearch

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'pagination' => [
           'pageSize' => 40,
        ],
        'query' => $query,

    ]);
```